# How do I split the screen into two areas, while having a form in the center?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I've been trying to achieve the below design for a couple of hours now but can't figure out the best way to approach this problem with Jetpack Compose, and I can't find a solid doc describing Compose's layout approach/guidelines.

I tried a bunch of things including the following nesting, but no luck:

```
Container
 Row - green background, align Top
 Row - white background, align Buttom
 Container (Form) - align Center
```

How can I achieve this design?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Stack Layout will help you. Like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MainContainer()
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun MainContainer() {
    Stack {

        Align(Alignment.TopCenter) {
            Column(arrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Container(
                    background(Color.Green),
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    //height = 350.dp,
                    width = 450.dp,
                    expanded = true
                ) {
                    Text("Up")
                }
            }
        }

        Align(alignment = Alignment.BottomCenter) {
            Column(background(Color.Yellow), arrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Container(alignment = Alignment.Center, height = 350.dp, width = 450.dp) {
                    Text("Down")
                }
            }
        }

        Align(Alignment.Center) {
            Column(background(Color.White), arrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Container(alignment = Alignment.Center, height = 250.dp, width = 250.dp) {
                    Clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) {
                        LoginContainer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LoginContainer() {
    Column {
        Text("Username")
        Text("Password")
        Button("Login")
    }
}
```

[image: You can see sample output here]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a parent `Box` with a gravity of center with a `Column` with two equal `Row`

```
@Composable
fun TwoAreas() {
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Column {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f).fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Red)) {
            }

            Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f).fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Blue)) {
            }
        }

        Box(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black).height(100.dp).width(100.dp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another answer because as per documentation "Stack was renamed to Box." and "gravity = ContentGravity.Center" it seems doesn’t exist anymore

```
@Composable
fun content(){
    Box {
        Column {
            Row(
                children = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(purple500)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
            Row(
                children = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(purple200)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Box layout as parent. Inside parent box layout, you can use two columns layout and one box layout for centre card. I am attaching sample screenshot and code snippet for your reference.

[Sample Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jip9w.png)

```
package com.webapp.democounter

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.webapp.democounter.ui.theme.DemoCounterTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DemoCounterTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    QuadrantScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun QuadrantScreen() {
    Box() {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Row(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                Quadrant(
                    heading = "Top Left Composable",
                    description = "Displays text and follows Material Designs guidelines",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Green)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .weight(1f)
                )
                Quadrant(
                    heading = "Top Right Composable",
                    description = "Displays text and follows Material Designs guidelines",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Yellow)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .weight(1f)
                )
            }
            Row(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                Quadrant(
                    heading = "Bottom Left Composable",
                    description = "Displays text and follows Material Designs guidelines",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Cyan)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .weight(1f)
                )
                Quadrant(
                    heading = "Bottom Right Composable",
                    description = "Displays text and follows Material Designs guidelines",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .weight(1f)
                )
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = 200.dp, height = 200.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .background(Color.Magenta)
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
            ) {
                Quadrant(
                    heading = "Center Composable",
                    description = "Displays text and follows Material Designs guidelines",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Quadrant(heading: String, description: String, modifier: Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        HeadingText(heading)
        DescriptionText(description)
    }
}

@Composable
fun HeadingText(heading: String = "Text Composable") {
    Text(
        text = heading,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
    )
}

@Composable
fun DescriptionText(heading: String = "") {
    Text(
        text = heading,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Justify
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    DemoCounterTheme {
        QuadrantScreen()
    }
}
```